# What does "clean" mean at the end of the title of an instrumental jazz song on Amazon Music?

Tags: jazz, song-title, amazon-music

I'm listening to Charles Mingus' 1959 album *Mingus Ah Um* on Amazon Music.  The titles of the majority of the track on this album are listed with "[Clean]" after the title:

[image: Mingus Ah Um on Amazon Music]

What does "[Clean]" mean in this context?  I would normally have thought that this refers to an alternate version with non-explicit (censored) lyrics, but the entire album is instrumental jazz with no lyrics on any track.

If it helps anyone figure it out, I have determined that this version of the album is a [later re-issue of the album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mingus_Ah_Um#Track_listing) with expanded uncut versions of several of the tracks as well as three tracks that were not on the original release.  However, the list of expanded tracks do not coincide with the tracks that have the "[Clean]" notation.

Comment: It could just be an error in the amazon database. Amazon does label clean versions of songs as [Clean] - e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Album-Version-feat-Cent-Clean/dp/B000WIR5G2 - and perhaps that's been done erroneously here.

Comment: @topomorto Yes, that probably makes the most sense.

Comment: Apparently *Fables of Faubus* does have some lyrics in some versions, so I read! Anyway, fantastic album IMO.

Comment: I don't see this tag in France...

Comment: @topomorto The version of that track with lyrics is called "Original Faubus Fables", and while they aren't explicit, they are angry.  But that track is one of the few tracks that does *not* have the [Clean] label.

Comment: Amazon Music has two versions of this album.  The one shown above they call ["Ah Um"](https://www.amazon.com/Ah-Um-Charles-Mingus/dp/B00138JAI6) with the tracks shown.  They also have one that they title ["Mingus Ah Um"](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00CK1QBAK) which is the original release with only 9 tracks, some of which are shorter.  On that one, none of the tracks are labeled [Clean].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a discussion [here](https://www.amazon.com/forum/autorip?_encoding=UTF8&cdForum=FxU80TLEAOLVK1&cdThread=TxE8FK57W4PNXV), these are probably censored versions of the songs.

**EDIT**: Answer from the Amazon support :

[image: Amazon support]

> The Clean version you see next to some of the Music titles means that the song/Album is edited out, like songs on the radio and does not contain any offensive content. Often swearing is taken out, lyrics deemed too violent for general people. Like how some TV shows have language bleeped out and scenes censored, it works the same way.

In that specific case, it is probably a mistake.

Comment: These are *instrumental* jazz songs.  There are no lyrics to be censored.

Comment: Yes... it might be stupid but I let my wrong answer here so other people don't make the same mistake.

Comment: @BenMiller An instrumental song can also qualify as "censored to the extreme" ;-)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer.  I originally thought there was more to it than that, but I guess it is simply someone at Amazon getting overzealous with the "Clean" label, applying it to a few instrumental tracks in which there are no Explicit versions.

Comment: @BenMiller, sometimes brass instruments can sound like farts, or guitars or flute like woman moans, maybe Amazon find this offensive.

Answer (score 4):

*Hypothetically*, and without doing a careful listen to the album...

It's not unusual for music recordings to pick up studio chatter or other unplanned voices. For example, the Kingsmen's classic recording of "Louie, Louie" includes the drummer yelling "fuck!" at one point when he dropped a drumstick. It's not part of the song lyrics or easy to make out, but it might be enough for there to be a "clean" version where it had been edited out.

So-- again hypothetically-- maybe that's what happened here? There are no vocals, but there were people near microphones. It's not impossible that something similar is at work.

Answer (score 0):

Clean is a remaster taken from an Unplayed vinyl.

Comment: Welcome to Music Fans. You could considerably improve your answer by editing it to provide references.